# Is there a MS Graph API endpoints that returns a list of Hidden teams?

Tags: microsoft-graph-teams

[Hide MS Team](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wEEfV.png)

The MS teams has an options to Hide a team, but the graph api https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/joinedTeams doesn't return this field, is there any way we can retrive a list of teams that are hide by a current login user?

explored the graph api

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation in the resource Properties, there is no property mentioned as "hide": https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/team?view=graph-rest-1.0#properties

You can raise a feature request for the same if you want this property:https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-developer-platform/idb-p/Microsoft365DeveloperPlatform

Hope this helps.